# Aggregate array size on multipme records MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have those objects

```
{_id:1, userId:1, elements:[1,2,3]},
{_id:2, userId:2, elements:[1,2]},
{_id:3, userId:1, elements:[1,2,3,4]},
```

I't like to get the number of elements by UserId, for example `1` have `7` elements and `2` have `2` elements

I tried

```
db.getCollection('user_elements').aggregate([
    {'$match': {userId: 1}},
    {'$project': {
        'elements': { $size: '$elements' }
    }}
]);
```

But In this case I have a first line with `3` and a second one with `4`.
Is there any solution to directly get `7` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it through [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

```
db.getCollection('user_elements').aggregate([
       {'$match': {userId: 1}}, 
       {$project: {elements: {$size: '$elements'}}}, 
       {$group: {_id: null, elements: {$sum: '$elements'}}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('user_elements').aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$userId", elements:{$sum:{$size:"$elements"}}}}])
```

Here, you want to sum the elements on the basis of userId. So, group it on the basis of userId, and $size will count the elements in the array and $sum will sum all the counts in the records containing same userId.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.